# jquery click dynamic component

Tags: jquery, click

I know I should use .on for attaching click event ty my dynamically added components. Actually, I DO use it in some components of my page and it does work.

here: http://cacharro.ole32.com/shopping/   you can see my page.

When you click in one of the sections (sorry for the spanish) it does interact with the click but when clicking over one of the inner elements the interaction does not happen.

This is the easy piece of code that should be working.

```
$(document).on('click', ".item",  function(){
    itemOnMarketClicked($(this));
});
```

No idea why it does not ....

EDIT1:

I noticed that when clicking the `$('#marketList').find('li:has(ul)').on('click',....` gets called. Can it be somehow the call does not get propagated inwards the list once it is catched here ???

Edit 2:
the code for intemMarketCliked was requested. here it is:

```
function itemOnMarketClicked(item){
     $("#currentList").append("<div class='itemOnList' id='List_"+item[0].id+"'>"+item[0].innerText+"</div>");
     item.slideUp(100, function(){item.remove()});
}
```

The idea is to append the clicked element in another list and delete it from the current list.

Comment: Post a fiddle not your site

Comment: I prefer to show my site because I fear the problem is collision between different parts of the site. The single statement works as expected, but not in my site, among all the other stuff.

Answer (score 1):

See as i see your code you have to put your `click` event outside of `init()` function so that it is always available to do the work as intended.

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', ".item",  function(){
        itemOnMarketClicked($(this));
    });
});
```

try putting all your click events outside of init function and as you have delegated the event to the `document` so you don't have to put it in doc ready block, it will work but still you have to put it outside of `init()` function.

Comment: it does not help firing the function, thanks anyway.

Comment: if you could post this func `itemOnMarketClicked()`

Comment: you can debug and notice  that the function does NOT get called. so its content are not really relevant. Anyhow I added the content for you in the question.

Comment: @javirs oh i saw your page and updated the answer you can try this.

Comment: I really thing this is not the problem since the other click functions work properly. The problem seems to rely on the click being catch by the `find('li:has(ul)').on('click'` and nowhere else